# Ansible Error: "[Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I'm not able to execute kubectl(v1.16.3) commands in the ansible command module.

For e.g. Creation of Namespace using ansible.

```
    tasks:
       - name: "Creating Directory"
         file:
           path: ~/ansible_ns/demo_namespaces
           state: directory

       - name: "Creating Namespaces(1/2)"
         copy:
           content: "apiVersion: v1 \nkind: Namespace \nmetadata: \n     name: {{item}} "
           dest: "~/ansible_ns/demo_namespaces/{{item}}.yml"
         with_items:
           - "{{ namespace }}"

       - name: "Creating Namespaces(2/2)"
         command: "kubectl create -f {{item}}.yml --kubeconfig=/var/lib/kubernetes/kubeconfig.yaml"
         args:
           chdir: ~/ansible_ns/demo_namespaces/
         ignore_errors: true
         with_items:
           - "{{ namespace }}"
```

I'm ending up with the below error:

```
(item=ns) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "cmd": "kubectl create -f ns.yml --kubeconfig=/var/lib/kubernetes/kubeconfig.yaml",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "kubectl create -f ns.yml --kubeconfig=/var/lib/kubernetes/kubeconfig.yaml",
            "_uses_shell": false,
            "argv": null,
            "chdir": "/root/ansible_ns/demo_namespaces/",
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "stdin_add_newline": true,
            "strip_empty_ends": true,
            "warn": true
        }
    },
    "item": "ns",
    "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory",
    "rc": 2
}
```

NOTE: But I'm able to do "kubectl create -f .." manually..and it is creating the stuff.

**My Ansible version:**

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.9.2
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/mdupaguntla/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Aug  4 2017, 00:39:18) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)]
```

FYI, I also tried with Ansible - 2.4.2 as well. But No luck.

**My System OS: CentOS 7**

**My queries:**

1. What is this error mean "[Errno 2] No such file or directory" in my context?
2. I came to know that Ansible introduced kubectl & k8s module: Is there anyone in the community using these.. If Yes, please let me know how to use them. If they any prerequisites - please share them
   For kubectl Module: Came to know that the pre-requisite is kubectl go library.May I know where can I 
                       get this Library.
3. when the kubectl version is 1.8 and ansible version is 2.4.2 - I'm able to get the K8s resources created using "kubectl create -f ..." using command module. But when I upgraded my cluster from v1.8 to v1.16.3 - I'm not able to create the resources using "kubectl create -f ..." using command module. Let me if I missed doing things.

Thanks in advance for the Community

Comment: provide the path for kubectl before the command or try using the shell command or try to give become: true

Comment: 1. If I use shell module. I'm getting "/bin/sh: kubectl: command not found".
2. I have already used below things 
     become: true
     become_method: sudo
     become_user: root
3. "provide the path for kubectl before the command" - like? - any example?

Comment: I  mean path for  kubectl. command: "/the/path/kubectl create -f {{item}}.yml. the path where kubectl exists

Comment: @smily - it's working.. thanks a lot... But why I should I place the path of kubectl in the command. Is there any workaround for that?

Answer (score 5):

You have to add the path for kubectl in the command module.

```
command: "/the/path/kubectl create -f {{item}}.yml .........."
```

This is because the $PATH is not updated with the path of kubectl. You can add the path to $PATH also instead of giving the path in command module.

Comment: My Kubectl is located in the path /usr/local/bin                                                                 
`echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin `                            
FYI, the kubectl path already there in the $PATH

Comment: May be the particular user's path variable doesnt have $PATH set with this. Try to echo $PATH from Ansible to verify that

Comment: shell: "echo $PATH"

Comment: Output of echo $PATH via Ansible: `"stdout_lines": ["/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:........."]`. It's having /usr/local/bin.

Comment: Oh then am sorry, that was my understanding, but I hope giving the path will fix your issue

Comment: ok will check my ansible configurations. If I find any.. will update here. Thanks for the responses and help.

Answer (score 1):

## Troubleshooting This Issue

The Error:

```
(item=ns) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "cmd": "kubectl create -f ns.yml --kubeconfig=/var/lib/kubernetes/kubeconfig.yaml",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "kubectl create -f ns.yml --kubeconfig=/var/lib/kubernetes/kubeconfig.yaml",
            "_uses_shell": false,
            "argv": null,
            "chdir": "/root/ansible_ns/demo_namespaces/",
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "stdin_add_newline": true,
            "strip_empty_ends": true,
            "warn": true
        }
    },
    "item": "ns",
    "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory",
    "rc": 2
}
```

First, notice that this states `"_uses_shell": false,`. This is because it is using `Command` instead of `shell`. This is also disguising the error code. If we switch to `shell` and re-run we get:

```
    "msg": "non-zero return code",
    "rc": 127,
    "start": "2021-09-03 13:48:12.184639",
    "stderr": "/bin/bash: <PROGRAM>: command not found",
```

(details on exit codes https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html )

The `/bin/bash` is the giveaway. Doing `which kubectl` you might get something like `/usr/local/bin/kubectl`.

You either need to update the ansible command to use `/usr/local/bin/kubectl` or update the $PATH for `/bin/bash/` to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are two ways to make this process better and functional.

You can try to use [k8s](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/k8s_module.html) module like this way.

```
- name: Create k8s catota namespace
  k8s:
    name: catota
    api_version: v1
    kind: Namespace
    state: present
```

Or you can use the [shell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html?highlight=shell) module as well:

```
- name: Create k8s catota namespace
  shell: "kubectl create namespace catota"
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
```

Comment: If I use shell module. I'm getting "/bin/sh: kubectl: command not found"

Comment: While using k8s Module: I'm getting this error "Failed to import the required Python library (openshift) on abc059.xyz.local's(Hostname of my VM) Python /usr/bin/python. Please read module documentation and install in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter". Is openshift need to be installed explictly at the path /usr/bin/python?- I'm new to this.

Comment: It seems a lot of people are facing the same error as yours. Looking for some issues on GitHub I came across one that might helps you: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/50529#issuecomment-451340890. About the shell module, it looks like your kubectl is not added on your $PATH in order to /bin/sh to used it. Can you execute `kubectl create ns namespace-name` manually on the host where you intend to run those ansible commands?

Comment: The shell module uses /bin/sh by default to run commands. Try to set bash shell instead. I edited my answer, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ansible 2.9.2, it has [k8s](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/k8s_module.html) module available. It provides fully declarative approach ( versus issuing imperative commands ) which is more similar to what you can find in kubernetes itself.

For example if you want to create a new namespace, just use:

```
- name: Create a k8s namespace
  k8s:
    name: testing
    api_version: v1
    kind: Namespace
    state: present
```

You have to admit it looks much simpler.

Comment: While using k8s Module: I'm getting this error"Failed to import the required Python library (openshift) on abc059.xyz.local's(Hostname of my VM) Python /usr/bin/python. Please read module documentation and install in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter". Is openshift need to be installed explictly at the path /usr/bin/python?- I'm new to this

Comment: Your `python interpreter` needs additional library `openshift` ( https://pypi.org/project/openshift/ ) to be able to handle operations required by `k8s` module. The easiest way to install it is by using your python package manager `pip`. You just need to run this command: `pip install openshift`.

Comment: I got a solution from smily. I'm going with that solution as I have to do minimal changes in my source code. I'll also try to use k8s module some other day and will let u know.. Thanks a lot for ur help as well..

Comment: I totally understand that you may prefer to use your current solution as its preparation required quite a lot of time and energy and it is practically ready. However, keep in mind that this is not a very flexible solution. Note that the existence of `shell` and `command` modules in **Ansible** is a kind of workaround for doing things that cannot be properly done with existing modules. Running imperative commands in your playbooks is contrary to the idea of [idempotency](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html), one of the core concepts present in **Ansible**.